# how to meteor react subscribe data bind in component?

Tags: reactjs, meteor, meteor-react

I am setting up a new meteor react app which subscribes new data from the server. I want to only bind data to main page component. I have following code  main page componen.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import RealTime from '../../../lib/client/RealTime';
    // TrackerReact is imported (default) with Meteor 1.3 new module system
    import TrackerReact from 'meteor/ultimatejs:tracker-react';
    import Game from '../pages/components/game';
    // > React.Component is simply wrapped with TrackerReact
    class MainPage extends TrackerReact(React.Component) {

        // Note: In ES6, constructor() === componentWillMount() in React ES5
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
              subscription: {
                tasks: Meteor.subscribe('userData')
              },
              data:{}
            }
        }

      getingData(){

        let data=RealTime.find().fetch();
        return data;

      }
        render() {


        const gamedata=this.getingData();
        console.log(this.getingData());

            return (
        <div className="container ">
                   <div className="board-player-top">
                                    <img className="user-pic" src="../../../../../images/player-img-top.png" alt="" title=""/>
                                        <div className="board-player-userTagline">
                                            <div className="user-tagline-component">
                                                <a href="#" target="_blank" className="user-tagline-username">Black Name</a> 
                                                <i>2202<img src="../../../../../images/user-flag.png" alt=""/></i>

                            </div> 
                                            <div className="captured-pieces">
                                            <img src="images/small-picW-1.png" /> <img src="images/small-picW-2.png" />
                                            </div>

                                            <div className="clock-top">
                                                10:00
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>

            <Game/>
             <div className="board-player-bottom">
                        <img className="user-pic" src="../../../images/player-img-bottom.png" alt="" title=""/>
                            <div className="board-player-userTagline">
                                <div className="user-tagline-component">
                                    <a href="#" target="_blank" className="user-tagline-username">Staick</a> <i>1576<img src="../../../images/user-flag.png" alt=""/></i>
                                </div>
                                <div className="captured-pieces">
                            <img src="images/small-picB-1.png" /> <img src="images/small-picB-2.png" />
                            </div> 
                                <div className="clock-bottom active">
                                    10:00
                                </div>
                            </div>
                </div>  

        </div>
            )

    }
    };
    export default MainPage
```

i have console.log(this.getingData()) inside render found
following data from serverside which automatically update.
[image]

Application comminucation with help of socket io other server and data publish to meteor client.application layout is following structer[image]

Comment: i advance sorry for poor english

Comment: You are essentially just dumping your code and asking us to turn it something that does something different. What have you tried so far? It doesn't look like you've even gone through the meteor-react tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass data to child component using props but here you can find problem each time you have received the gamedata pass as props to child component then child component will update.
You should simantanilious pass data to each child component.